# PHP finding functions in a string

Tags: php, parsing

I am trying to search and replace functions in a string to add `<span>` tags to it with a class for syntax highlighting; however, my regex knowledge is lousy and I can't seem to find a good resource for learning the ins and outs of it.

Here is what I have so far:

```
$line = 'function test( $param ) {';

$pattern = '*\(/';
preg_match_all($pattern, $line, $matches);
foreach ($matches as $match){
    $line = preg_replace($pattern, '<span class="syntax_fs">'.$match.'</span>(', $line);
}

echo $line;
```

Comment: You want a parser, not a regex, and have you looked into [`highlight_string()`](https://php.net/highlight-string)?

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol, Thank you! I actually had no idea that existed; however, I can't seem to get it to work on a dark background. Any suggestions?

Comment: _.. I can't seem to get it to work on a dark background..._ You can change the colors of the highlighting or even of your background

Comment: @B001ᛦ, that was super helpful! I figured out how to replace the colors, and it works.

Answer (score -1):

Use something like

- PHP function `token_get_all()` or class `PhpToken` (PHP8, [my polyfill for PHP5+](https://gist.github.com/WinterSilence/7584564280d27980bc08cd1e35c0f2df))
- [AST PHP parser](https://github.com/nikic/php-parser)

See as example https://gist.github.com/WinterSilence/6f743f646315c363779df286f9a663cc#file-vardumper-php-L143

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/30290499)

Comment: @kiner_shah Iink to actual version better, - i'm can't update my answers at updates in gist